# Cannot modify bash history inside command_not_found_handle function

Tags: bash, command-history, command-not-found

I'm trying to make my own `command_not_found_handle` function, which on given a wrong command, asks the user with the most identical command if that was what he meant. If the user accepts that suggestion then it should delete the last command (the wrong command) from the history and add the selected one. But it isn't working.

This is my code

```bash
command_not_found_handle(){
  ....

  # replace the previous wrong command with the correct one in bash history
  history -d -1
  history -s "$command $@"
}
```

When I enter a wrong command and select one from the suggestion, it doesn't modify the history. But if I call the function myself e.g.

```bash
command_not_found_handle wrong_command
```

It updates the history, removing the `wrong_command` and appending the new one.

I verified that the function has read access to the history in both cases by calling the `history` command inside the function, which returns the history list. But in the first case it cannot write to the history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems is not possible using directly the `command_not_found_handle` function.

According to `man bash`:

> If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function named command_not_found_handle.  If that function exists, it is invoked in a separate execution environment with the  original command  and  the original command's arguments as its arguments.

So all changes in `history`, `variables`, etc. will be lost. For example, having this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
val=10

command_not_found_handle() {
  echo Val is $val
  val=50
  echo Val now is $val
}
```

Before running any non-existent command you should try to print the value of `val`:

```bash
(bash shell)> echo $val
#Output
10
```

Now if you type any command which does not exist e.g. `ls4` and print `val` you will get this:

```bash
(bash shell)> ls4
#Output
Val is 10
Val now is 50
(bash shell)> echo $val
#Output
10
```

As you can see above, the final values was `50` but when the `command_not_found_handle` finished the final value was `10`.

That happens basically because it's running a `bash` subshell. You can check it by using the following:

```
val=10

command_not_found_handle() {
  echo Val is $val
  val=50
  echo Val now is $val
  
  echo "Parent bash PID: $$"
  echo "BASH PID: $BASHPID"

  #echo $BASH_SUBSHELL #NOTE If I'm not wrong this should print `1` but 
 # it prints 0 (which is the current level of the bash parent shell). I'm not sure why.

  echo -e "\nUsing ps\n"
  ps
}
```

And again if you run a non-existent command you will get something like this:

```
(bash shell)> ls4
#Output
Val is 10
Val now is 50
Parent bash PID: 15399
BASH PID: 15420

Using ps

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
10561 pts/3    00:00:00 zsh
15399 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
15420 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
15421 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

As you can see the `command_not_found_handle` is running in a shell with `PID: 15420`. Therefore the `val` variable lost the value `50` when the `command_not_found_handle` finishes.

**Possible solution:**

You should save the *correct* command into a file and with one of the following three ways modify the history:

Your `command_not_found_handle` function should look like this:

```bash
command_not_found_handle() {
  echo "$1: command not found" >&2
  read -p "What did you mean? " cmd
  echo -n "$cmd" > '/tmp/cmd.txt'
}
```

Now you should create a function to modify your history:

```bash
checkHist(){
   [ -f  '/tmp/cmd.txt' ] && {
      h="$(cat /tmp/cmd.txt)"
      history -d -1
      history -s "$h"
      rm '/tmp/cmd.txt'
   }
}
```

Finally you have three options to modify the history easily:

**Solution 1:** Using `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='checkHist'
```

With the code above, when a command is executed, the content inside `PROMPT_COMMAND` will be executed after (in this case the `checkHist` function). So this is the easiest way because it does all automatically.

**Solution 2:** Binding a key/shortcut

```bash
bind -x '"\C-p":checkHis'
```

With the code above the function `checkHis` will be executed when you press: <kbd>Ctrl+p</kbd>

**Solution 3:** Using a short alias

```bash
alias u="checkHist"
```

With this alias you can modify the history by using/typing the `u` letter in your terminal.